# C# .NET 7 Include and load resources with .csproj

Tags: c#, .net, csproj, .net-7.0

I am trying to include resources via csproj file to a C# .NET 7 app and then use them (get a byte array or something), there are some resources online to this but none of them worked for me and many of them were outdated. I made some code how it probably like but all load resource functions I tried couldn't find a resource. (No errors or warnings)

```
dotnet publish -r win-x86 -c Release --self-contained true /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

namespace Program{
    class Program{
        static void Main(){
                    GetRes("Program.Build2.png");
        }

        public static byte[] GetRes(string resName)
                {
                    var assembly = typeof(MyLibrary.MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                    Stream resource = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName);
                    return StreamToByteArray(resource);
        }

                public static byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream input)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        input.CopyTo(ms);
                        return ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="this.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Build2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I wanted to load resources but the functions I tried always returned null.

Comment: Then you have the wrong name. Get a list of all the embedded ressources and print out tue names ;) Btw., ou can leave out the {} on the using and make i a using satement ( as in: using var ms = new MemoryStream(); - new syntax, gets discarded at the end o f the method.

Comment: Does it work without `--self-contained true /p:PublishSingleFile=true` params?

Comment: @TomTom Thank you, that solved my problem. I didn't thought of listing resources. I have to use the c# file name (app.cs) instead of the namespac. So not program.file.txt it is app.file.txt to load resources.

Comment: @Misaz No, I used wrong names.

Comment: The embedded resources use the root namespace of the project and the default for the root namespace is the name of the project. You can control the namespace of the embedded resources by setting the `RootNamespace` property, e.g. in the `<PropertyGroup>` in the project file add `<RootNamespace>Program</RootNamespace>`. (`RootNamespace` is documented in "[Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022)".)